# Excel VB: add Cell to existing Name

Tags: vba, excel, named-ranges

I'm trying to add a Cell to an existing Name via VB.

My best Attempt looks like this:

```
Tabelle1.Names("delCase").RefersTo = Tabelle1.Names("delCase").RefersTo + ";" + Target.Address
```

But this prompts a

> Application- or objectdefined Error

Comment: I don't fully understand the context of your code - is this within an event procedure?

Comment: That is the error that you get when have an unhandled VBA error.  If you add error-handling, you will be able to find out the actual VBA error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (**TRIED AND TESTED**)

```
Union(Tabelle1.Range("delCase"), Target).Name = "delCase"
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of trying to assign a string to `RefersTo`, you can directly assign a `Range` (as `RefersTo` is of type `variant`). Changing your line slightly to:

```
Tabelle1.Names("delCase").RefersTo = Tabelle1.Range("delCase;" & Target.Address)
```

Then works as expected.

If you'd like a more elegant way to do this, try:

```
Tabelle1.Range("delCase;" & Target.Address).Name = "delCase"
```

Comment: Hmmm, I am unable to get either one working... But 3 upvotes mean that beside you 3 of them got it working so I am definitely missing something :)

Comment: Ah I see what the problem is... You are using ";". I guess you have a dutch version. This method will not work on all systems due to their regional settings. It is best that you use union method.

Comment: @SiddharthRout I was writing the code in the locale of the OP (German I would guess).

Comment: Yes. I still feel `Union` is a better option than using ";" or ",". There is no scope for confusion and the code will work in all versions :)